# Balanced Binary Search Tree Search Function

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am writing a code for a fruit mart where every user's data is stored in a binary tree. when a user wants to login, he should enter his username. the program should search for the username in the tree and execute the related function.

The search function returns the correct value when the username is not present and shows the appropriate message but it doesn't display any message or error when the username is found.( According to the program it should display 'Hello'). By using 'inorder' function I checked if the tree is forming correctly- it is properly formed. Attached is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class node                  //Create a class for node.
{  public:
    char First_Name[30];
    char Last_Name[30];
    char Email_id[50];
    int long Phone;
    char Username[20];
    char Location[25];
    node *lc;
    node *rc;
    int h;
    friend class avl;

};

class avl                   //Create a class for avl.
{public:
    node* root;
    avl()
    {
        root=NULL;          //Initialise root to NULL.
    }
    node *insert(node *root,char[],char[],char[],char[],char[],int long);
    void insert1();
    int height(node *);
    int bal_fac(node*);
    node *LL(node*);
    node *LR(node*);
    node *RL(node*);
    node *RR(node*);
    int search(char[]);                                  
    node *getinfo(char[]);
    void inorder(node*);
};

void avl::inorder(node *root)   //To print the inorder sequence.
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return ;
    else
    {
        inorder(root->lc);
        cout<<root->Username<<" ";
        inorder(root->rc);
    }
}

void avl:: insert1()        //Insert1 function to read file contents.
{
    char firstname[30]=" ";
    char lastname[30]=" ";
    char email_id[50]=" ";
    int long contact=0;
    char name[20];
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your First name: ";
    cin>>firstname;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your Last name: ";
    cin>>lastname;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your Email id: ";
    cin>>email_id;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your phone number: ";
    cin>>contact;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl<<"Enter your User name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cin.ignore();
    int len=strlen(name);
    len+=4;
    char file[len];

    fstream myfile;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
    {
        file[i]=name[i];
    }
    file[i++]='.';
    file[i++]='t';
    file[i++]='x';
    file[i++]='t';
    file[i]='\0';

    myfile.open(file,ios::app); //To read from file using object myfile.
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {

        myfile<<"Item\t\tQuantity\t\tTime "<<endl;
        root=insert(root,firstname,lastname,email_id,name,file,contact);   
        myfile.close();
            }
    else
        cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl;

            }

int avl::search(char username[20])
{
    int flag=0;

    node *ptr;
    ptr=root;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        int a=strcmp(ptr->Username,username);                          
        if (a>0)                  //if the entered word is smaller than ptr
            ptr=ptr->lc;                    //traverse left sub-tree
        else
            if (a<0)              //if the entered word is greater than ptr
                ptr=ptr->rc;                //traverse right sub-tree
            else
                if(a==0)               //if ptr is the entered word
                {
                    flag=1;
                    cout<<"Heyy!!";
                    return flag;
                }
    }
    return flag;
}

node* avl::getinfo(char username[20])
{
    node *ptr;
    node *temp;
    ptr=root;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        int a=strcmp(ptr->Username,username);                          
        if (a>0)                //if the entered word is smaller than ptr
            ptr=ptr->lc;                   //traverse left sub-tree
        else
            if (a<0)          //if the entered word is greater than ptr
                ptr=ptr->rc;                   //traverse right sub-tree
            else
                if(a==0)                //if ptr is the entered word
                {
                    temp=ptr;
                }
    }
    return temp;
}

node *avl::insert(node *root,char firstname[30], char lastname[30], char email_id[50], char username[20], char filename[25], long int number)
{
    int bal;
    if(root==NULL)                  //Initial node
    {
        root=new node;
        strcpy(root->First_Name,firstname);
        strcpy(root->Last_Name,lastname);
        strcpy(root->Email_id,email_id);
        root->Phone=number;
        strcpy(root->Username,username);
        strcpy(root->Location,filename);
        root->lc=NULL;
        root->rc=NULL;
        root->h=0;
        return(root);
    }
    if(strcmp(username,root->Username)<0)//Inserted node is smaller than root.
    {
 root->lc=insert(root->lc,firstname,lastname,email_id,username,filename,number);
        bal=bal_fac(root);      //Calculate balance factor.
        if(bal==2)      //Left child of unbalanced node is affected.
        {
            if(strcmp(username,root->lc->Username)<0)
        {
                   root=LL(root);   //Left sub-tree is affected.
        }
            else
                root=LR(root);      //Right sub-tree is affected.
        }
    }
    else            //Inserted node is greater than root.
        {
            root->rc=insert(root->rc,firstname,lastname,email_id,username,filename,number);//Insert to the right.
            bal=bal_fac(root);      //Calculate balance factor.
            if(bal==-2)     //Right child of unbalanced node is affected.
            {
                if(strcmp(username,root->rc->Username)>0)
                    root=RR(root) ; //Right sub-tree is affected.
                else
                    root=RL(root);  //Left sub-tree is affected.

            }
        }
        root->h=height(root);       //Calculate height of node.
        return(root);
    }


int avl::height(node*root)
{
    int lh,rh;

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    if (root->lc==NULL)
    lh= 0;
    else
    lh= 1+root->lc->h;

        if (root->rc==NULL)
            rh= 0;
            else
            rh= 1+root->rc->h;
        if(lh>rh)
            return lh;
        else
            return rh;
}
int avl::bal_fac(node *root)
{
    if (root== NULL)
    return 0;
    int lh=0;

    if (root->lc==NULL)
    lh= 0;
    else
    lh= 1+height(root->lc);
    int rh=0;
    if (root->rc==NULL)
        rh= 0;
        else
        rh= 1+height(root->rc);
    int bf=lh-rh;
    return bf;
}
node *avl::LL(node *root)
{
    node *temp;
temp=root->lc;
root->lc=temp->rc;
temp->rc=root;
temp->h=height(temp);
root->h=height(root);
cout<<"LL"<<endl;
return temp;        //Return the new root.


}
node *avl::RR(node *root)
{
    node *temp;
    temp=root->rc;
    root->rc=temp->lc;
    temp->lc=root;
    temp->h=height(temp);
    root->h=height(root);
    cout<<"RR"<<endl;
    return temp;        //Return the new root.
}
node *avl::LR(node *root)
{
    root->lc=RR(root->lc);

    root=LL(root);
    cout<<"LR"<<endl;
    return root;        //Return the new root.

}
node *avl::RL(node *root)
{
    root->rc=LL(root->rc);

    root=RR(root);
    cout<<"RL"<<endl;
    return root;        //Return the new root.
}


int main() {
    avl a;
    int user=0;
    char ch,uname[20]=" ",choice;
    cout<<endl<<"Welcome to XYZ Fruit Mart!!!"<<endl;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Are you an existing customer?"<<endl;
        cout<<"(Press y/Y for yes or n/N for no):  ";
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Enter your Username:  ";
            cin>>uname;
            user=a.search(uname);
            if(user==0)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"THIS USERNAME DOES NOT EXIST. PLEASE CHECK YOUR USERNAME AGAIN";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Hello";
                a.activity(uname);
            }
        }
        if(ch=='n'||ch=='N')
        {
            cout<<endl<<"Create your own login with us to use our services.";
            a.insert1();
            cout<<endl<<"Your Account is now created. Login again to acess services.";
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Do you want to login again? (Press y/Y for yes or n/N for no):  ";
        cin>>choice;
    }while(choice=='y'||choice=='Y');


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try flushing the cout before calling "activity()" ?

Comment: This wasn't the error but it helped me zoom in to find the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory corruption in `insert1()`.

When you create a file name, you are adding 4 to the length of the name in order to be able to add ".txt".  Unfortunately, you do not count the ending '\0' and this may cause a lot of collateral damage.

Correct the length:

```
int len = strlen(name);
len += 5;
```

I played a little bit arround with the corrected code, and it works as expected (I commented out a.activitiy() because it was not defined).

### Important remarks:

You are using variable length arrays (`char file[len];`).  This may work on some compiler but is no part of the C++ standard and is not portable. Better forget it.  Instead of using such char arrays and C style `strxxx()` functions, consider seriously using c++ `std::string`

From the point of view of the design, it is not optimal to manage I/O or application commands in functions of the AVL class.  I/O is here more related to nodes and should be managed as member function of the node, or as overload of a standarad extractor.

Comment: I changed the code to len+=5 and it worked. After writing the activity function I changed it to 4 again just to see what happens, but surprisingly it worked.

Comment: Also, I'll try doing it with std::string after I am done with this executing this program properly. I'll keep in mind these tips.

Comment: These memory corruption errors are very nasty. It may work by coincidence, break immediately when it happens, or cause some unnoticed damage that will cause some other parts of the code to fail without reason later in the execution flow. It's "undefined behaviour" and not predictible.